# OnePlus 9 phone doesn't give my app internet when debugging but works fine otherwise

Tags: android, android-14, oneplusx

Ever since updating my test OnePlus 9 to Android 14, when I install my app as production it works fine, but when I install it as debug, I don't get internet. I just get `ECONNREFUSED`.

It works perfectly fine on my other test phones with Android 14.

Is there some special permission or something I need on the OS of the OnePlus 9?

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` means that you have internet, else it would be "no route to host". It is rather unlikely this has anything to do with OnePlus, while your "error description" is pretty much alike "it's not working". Could in best case imagine, that it doesn't care about "cleartextTrafficPermitted" network-configuration.

Comment: I have the `cleartextTrafficPermitted` attribute set to `true` but that is the same on both debug and release. If I switch to the release variant then it works fine. My pixels don't have this issue. This is the first phone I've encountered this on after 10 years of working on this app.

Comment: I tested removing all the network security configs and that didn't help.